# Duplication on cache update in urql - urql, GraphQL, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, caching, graphql, urql

**UPDATE:** I investigated how new records are being cached, and I found that:

- On the first insert (`new1`), it adds an extra record to the current (first used) query (default query: `[new1,...]`, first used: `[new1,new1,...]`).
- On the second insert, it adds **the previous insert** (`new1`) to the default query, and still, an extra record to the first used query (default query: `[new2,new1,new1,...]`, first used query: `[new2,new2,new1,new1,...]`, second: `[new2,new1,...]`—correct).
- This second step keeps happening for every new insert, but the second used query and next queries are not affected (I checked up to four queries).

---

I have the query `createMeanings` and the mutation `readMeanings`. When news records (of type `Meaning`) is created, I want it to appear on top of the table.

The arguments for `readMeanings` are like this: `{options: {limit: 5, sorting: {by: "createdAt", order: "DESC"}}}`. So I have multiple `readMeanings` queries.

The problem is, oftentimes (but not always) the newly created record is doubled or even tripled in the cache.

Here's my cache update, which I took from [the docs](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/cache-updates/#updating-many-unknown-links):

```ts
createMeanings: (result, args, cache, info) => {
  const newMeanings = (result as CreateMeaningsMutation)
    .createMeanings.meanings;
  if (newMeanings) {
    cache
      .inspectFields("Query")
      .filter((field) => field.fieldName === "readMeanings")
      .forEach((field) => {
        cache.updateQuery(
          {
            query: ReadMeaningsDocument,
            variables: field.arguments as QueryReadMeaningsArgs,
          },
          (data: ReadMeaningsQuery | null) => {
            if (data?.readMeanings.meanings) {
              console.log("field.arguments:", field.arguments);
              console.log("newMeanings", newMeanings);
              data.readMeanings.meanings = [
                ...newMeanings,
                ...data.readMeanings.meanings,
              ];
              // Or: data.readMeanings.unshift(...newMeanings);
            }
            console.log("data", data);
            return data;
          }
        );
      });
  }
},
```

When I look at the logs, I see something like this:

`[Log] field.arguments: – {options: {limit: 10, sorting: {by: "updatedAt", order: "DESC"}}}`*

`data.readMeanings.meanings has 6 records`

`[Log] field.arguments: – {options: {limit: 5, sorting: {by: "createdAt", order: "DESC"}}}`

`data.readMeanings.meanings has 7 records`

And out of these 7 records, the two on top are duplicates of the newly-created record.

It's as if `data` was somehow shared between these two queries.

Am I not seeing something super obvious? Any advice would be appreciated!

*Don't know if that's relevant, but those arguments are default, and I load actual arguments from `localStorage` using `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

I think found a workaround:

The problem must be related to my default query and how I load actual arguments from `localStorage` using `useEffect`.

I don't see duplicates if I don't update the default query (at index `0`):

```ts
if (newMeanings) {
  const fieldInfos = cache
    .inspectFields("Query")
    .filter((field) => field.fieldName === "readMeanings")
  const sliceStart = fieldInfos.length > 1 ? 1 : 0;
  fieldInfos.slice(sliceStart, fieldInfos.length).forEach((field) => {
    cache.updateQuery(
      ...
    );
```

However I can't really explain why this seems to work, so feel free to correct me.